# Info light button Placement and transition

Tags: xcode, button, uinavigationbar, modal-dialog, transition

In the apps that i have seen, info light buttons are all in the navigation bar and when touched, the transition to a new view is a horizontal flip. Is it okay if i make an application that does not have the info light button in the navigation bar and when touched, uses the push animation to transfer the user to a new view? If not, could someone tell me how to code for the horizontal flip because when i choose Modal and flip and connect to a view, nothing happens when pressed (but works if if i choose push instead of modal.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the FAQ so you can get higher quality answers to your questions.

Please provide some information as to exactly what you want, what you have tried so far, and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what ever you want. There is no guideline for what kind of button should cause what kind of view change.

Here's a couple of examples of how to change view controllers:

```
//if you are using xibs use this line
UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myXib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
//if you are using storyboards use this line
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewControllersID"];

[controller setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
//this sets the modal transition style

//to present the controller modally use this
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
//or if you are pushing to this controller using a navigation controller use this
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```